# Changing WCF endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have create a solution contains two projects Asp.net web site and a service. I am trying to add service reference to site project but VS fired an error.

```
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost2:53480/FondSerivce.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

stackoweflow deny a localhost link, so I have whire localhost2 here.

so. The interesting is **if I change endpoint configuration of service where is no result**. The messages are the same.

the soap 1.1 is 
'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

As i understand server at any way need soap 1.1 request.
Here is a part of service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="configuration_soap12"/> 
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="FondService.FondSvc">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="configuration_soap12" contract="FondService.IFondService"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Why service ask for `text/xml` if I using wsHttpBinding? Or may be my config is wrong?

Comment: Aren't you missing an address in the config?

Comment: So. now I have added address="http://localhost:53480/FondSerivce.svc", the same result...

Comment: How do you call the service? Have you tried using a normal basicHttpBinding?

Comment: I am not calling it now. Im just trying to add service to references in VS. About basicHttpBinding yes i have.

Comment: What do you get if you browse to http://localhost2:53480/FondSerivce.svc then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64714/discussion-between-jontatas-and-user2598575).